# How to get UTC time from phpmyadmin using php?

Tags: php, sql

I added current time using php in phpmyadmin timestamp using current_timestamp, and my phpmyadmin database is below.[image: browser recored]
[image: structure]

here is my sql when insert record.`$query3 = "INSERT INTO ecs_user_register (UserID, Email, Password, Activited, ActivationCode, RegisteredTime)  VALUES (DEFAULT, '$emailAddress', '$password', '1', '$activationCode', DEFAULT)";`

When I get this record from phpmyadmin, here is my code,`$query1 = "SELECT Activited, RegisteredTime From ecs_user_register WHERE Email = '$emailAddress' AND ActivationCode = '$activationCode'";`

My question is how do I get time with timezone? the result is only "2017-10-29 00:28:27" but could not retrieve with time zone"-0500"?, or how do I insert this record with UTC time zone?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

Comment: What type is the `RegisteredTime` column -- `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: @duskwuff as image, it is TIMESTAMP